# process exit and impact on threads

Tags: c++, linux, unix, process, operating-system

Under maintenance, I see that the project code (in `c/c++`  on linux) calls `libc` `exit` function in-case of some un-recoverable error. However, this process termination call is used across multiple threads (each when it faces unrecoverable scenario). Now -

- Can the process `exit` be called from thread other than main thread without any side effects.
- Whenever `exit` is called (either in main thread or any other thread), does it guarantee graceful exit of the threads.

I understand that the standard (man pages) is silent about it, and the best way to do is, initiate a graceful termination of all threads and using notification mechanism, `main` thread must be notified for graceful termination. However, since it is a project under maintenance, want to check if current behavior is correct before changing.

Issue I am facing is, I can see random  crashes where one of the thread is under the due process of `exit` call execution.

Comment: 'random crashes' - what are the symptoms, what happens that should not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, when you call `exit` (from any thread, main or child) the process exits immediately.

For the second question, see the answer above. In short, no. Threads will not exit "gracefully" (from the applications perspective anyway).

Comment: I agree with you, but during the process of exit, if the another thread is executing, will it cause a crash? Does the exit in kernel mode, ensure that other threads are blocked?

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran I don't think it's specified that threads will be killed in a specific order, so I think it would not be unlikely that weird things may happen. If you can replicate the crashes, then I suggest you run your application in a debugger to see when and where the crashes happen.

Comment: I would think that such 'crashes' would be rare. The OS does stop all threads on all cores before freeing resources owned by the process, so it's difficult to come up with scenarios where any sort of fault might be raised during process termination.